# Limestone versus granite for yard edging

Tags: masonry

I am looking at adding some stone edging to my yard and possibly building some steps. The stone seller advised me against limestone, as he said it would stain and deteriorate rapidly compared to granite.

Seeing as how the pyramids are still standing after 4000 years and they are made of limestone I don't really understand this.

Is there some concrete reason to prefer granite?

Comment: The pyramids are in the desert. Are you? To gauge your local acid rain situation, go find an old graveyard with granite and marble headstones. Marble is glorified limestone. Compare the state of stones from the same era in different materials.

Comment: @Ecnerwal It does rain in Egypt you know.

Comment: 17mm per year, on average, where the pyramids are. http://en.climate-data.org/location/551/

Answer (score 2):

[Limestone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limestone) is soluble in water, especially acidic water (e.g. [acid rain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acid_rain)). That's why Florida has so many sinkholes; it's a type of [karst](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karst) topography where the water table dissolves the underlying limestone until the surface soil collapses into the void.

So, no: limestone isn't a good candidate for any stone edging that you'd want to be durable. It would be really bad for steps.

Comment: Some people insist on using marble for kitchen counter tops. Ordinary vinegar will etch it. Acidic drinks will too.

Answer (score 0):

Limestone may last 100 years or more in many applications. Granite could last 1000s of years. How long do you need it to last and what is the difference in cost?